# Bluetooth headphones keep disconnecting

Tags: bluetooth, headphones, connection, blueman

I'm trying to connect Sony WH-CH510 to Ubuntu 22.04.
Pairing works OK,
but connecting never resolves - I get a "Connected" message, but after a minute it disconnects again, and the headphones never show up in pulseaudio output.

Error messages vary, including

```
bluetoothd src/device.c:search_cb() error updating services: Input/output error

unexpected start frame

ServicesResolved: no
```

Especially puzzling is that everything works fine on a different computer, also running Ubuntu 22.04.

Here's some info.  Let me know what else would be helpful.

```
$ sudo service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Sat 2022-07-30 14:01:06 EDT; 1s ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 188402 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 38277)
     Memory: 812.0K
        CPU: 53ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─188402 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

Jul 30 14:01:06 BL-CITO-8BL5JL2 bluetoothd[188402]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.347 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/aptx
Jul 30 14:01:06 BL-CITO-8BL5JL2 bluetoothd[188402]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.347 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/aptx
Jul 30 14:01:06 BL-CITO-8BL5JL2 bluetoothd[188402]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.347 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc
Jul 30 14:01:06 BL-CITO-8BL5JL2 bluetoothd[188402]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.347 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc
Jul 30 14:01:06 BL-CITO-8BL5JL2 bluetoothd[188402]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.347 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_453
Jul 30 14:01:06 BL-CITO-8BL5JL2 bluetoothd[188402]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.347 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_453
Jul 30 14:01:06 BL-CITO-8BL5JL2 bluetoothd[188402]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.347 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_512
Jul 30 14:01:06 BL-CITO-8BL5JL2 bluetoothd[188402]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.347 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_512
Jul 30 14:01:06 BL-CITO-8BL5JL2 bluetoothd[188402]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.347 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSink/sbc_xq_552
Jul 30 14:01:06 BL-CITO-8BL5JL2 bluetoothd[188402]: Endpoint registered: sender=:1.347 path=/MediaEndpoint/A2DPSource/sbc_xq_552

$ pactl list | grep blue
Name: module-bluetooth-policy
    module.description = "Policy module to make using bluetooth devices out-of-the-box easier"
Name: module-bluetooth-discover
Name: module-bluez5-discover
```

Could this be a hardware conflict of some kind?

Edit 1:  The pulseaudio-module-bluetooth is already installed:

```
$ sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
pulseaudio-module-bluetooth is already the newest version (1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Another error message from journalctl:

```
bluetoothd[188402]: src/device.c:search_cb() 74:45:CE:1A:C6:2E: error updating services: Input/output error (5)
```

Edit 2:

```
lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 413c:2113 Dell Computer Corp. KB216 Wired Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 018: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd Galaxy A5 (MTP)
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Is Cambridge Silicon Radio unreliable?

Comment: Can you connect other devices to this computer?

Comment: I'm using a Logitech bluetooth mouse.  I should try another headset though...

Comment: I am asking because I am trying to find out do we need to do something with BT drivers on Ubuntu. Anyway please add output of `lspci- knn | grep Net -A3; lsusb` command.

Comment: `Cambridge Silicon Radio` is a problem device.

Comment: So you think it's worth trying another adapter?  How about ASUS?

Comment: Another adapter is a good idea. Brand names mean nothing hear. It depends on what chip is used there. But likely ASUS uses a good chip, not this "noname" one.

Comment: Does this look good?  http://en.techinfodepot.shoutwiki.com/wiki/ASUS_USB-BT400

Comment: Or the newer one:  https://www.asus.com/us/Networking-IoT-Servers/Adapters/All-series/USB-BT500/techspec/

Comment: These names don't tell anything unless you insert and run lsusb ;-)

Comment: `UB 400` seems to be the same Silicon Radio ;-) But it works sometimes. There is  lot of modifications of that chip. But maybe the problem is with your device. That's why I asked if other devices, e.g. a mouse work with that dongle.

Comment: The headphones work with a different computer (also Ubuntu 22.04), so it's not that

Comment: Here's the ASUS BT500:
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 0b05:190e ASUSTek Computer, Inc. ASUS USB-BT500

Comment: This should be OK. It is Realtek 8761BU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to ASUS BT500 adapter solved the problem.  Thanks Pilot6.

Answer (score 0):

Run these two commands:

`sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth`

`killall pulseaudio`

Try to connect again.

[Solution source](https://github.com/blueman-project/blueman/issues/547)

Comment: Please be a little cautious with using *exact* copy and paste answers for slightly different questions on AU...